# Problems uninstalling software from store or terminal and problem with command sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, uninstall

I am a user of ubuntu recently, since I had windows and wanted to be in another air so to speak, the version of ubuntu is 22.04, well the two problems are the following:

1. When I download a software with the .deb and I install everything fine, the problem comes when I want to uninstall it, it sends me to the store and according to that, it gives me the option to uninstall it, but I get another application that I have to install and I don't know what I can do in those cases and when I try to do it from the finish and I put this command:

   `sudo apt -purge remove (example of some software)`

gives me this message: The command line option "p" [for -purge] combined with the other options makes no sense.

or when I put this command:

`sudo snap remove (example of some software)`
gives me this result: snap "(example of some software)" is not installed

2. the other problem i have is that when i put this command:

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
   gives me this error:
   404 Not Found followed by some error gives me that See the apt-secure(8) manual page which according to it is a repositories problem but in the same way I already checked that page and do what it indicates and it just keeps giving me an error.

I look forward to your help and thank you for taking the trouble.

Comment: 1. Use `sudo apt purge <package>` or `sudo apt remove --purge <package>`. 2. Please provide the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` if all the sources are reachable using ping and if they resolve.